# Squid ERROR: Invalid ACL with external ACL

Tags: authentication, ubuntu, proxy, acl, squid

I cannot get Squid to work with an external ACL.

The error I get is:

`Can't use proxy auth because no authentication schemes are fully configured. FATAL: ERROR: Invalid ACL: acl ext_acl external acl_name`

Here is my whole config file:

```html
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80
acl Safe_ports port 21
acl Safe_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 70
acl Safe_ports port 210
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535
acl Safe_ports port 280
acl Safe_ports port 488
acl Safe_ports port 591
acl Safe_ports port 777
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
external_acl_type acl_name %SRC %LOGIN %DST /etc/squid/ext_acl.py
acl ext_acl external acl_name
http_access allow ext_acl
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

Here is the external ACL python script:

```html
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import logging
import time

def grant ():
      sys.stdout.write('OK\n')
      sys.stdout.flush()

def deny ():
      sys.stdout.write('ERR\n')
      sys.stdout.flush()

while True:
      line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
      if line:
              deny()
      else:
              time.sleep( 1 )
```

The python script is owned by the proxy user and has 777 permissions on it.

Executing it from the terminal shows that the script works fully as expected.

Any ideas?